# Creating hollow pyramid with solid top layer in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create a hollow pyramid with a solid top layer like so:

Height: 5

```
     *
    ***
   *   *
  *     *
 *********
```

Also needs a user input for height/number of rows, so it can't just be hardcoded, for example with a height of 4:

```
    *
   ***
  *   *
 *******
```

---

Using this code I received this output with no solid layer on top:

```
     *
    * *
   *   *
  *     *
 *********
```

---

```
n = 5
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n - i - 1):
        print(' ', end='')

    for k in range(2 * i + 1):
        if k == 0 or k == 2 * i:
            print('*', end='')
        else:
            if i == n - 1:
                print('*', end='')
            else:
                print(' ', end='')
    print()
```

Comment: So it looks like you need to do something different in the case where `i == 1`. If only there were some programming construct that allowed you to do two different things based on some condition. I think, if I invented that, I may call it `if` :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a modified version of your code that prints the triangle correctly. Note the change to the if statements.

```
n = 5
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n - i - 1):
        print(' ', end='')

    for k in range(2 * i + 1):
        if k in [0,2*i]:
            print('*', end='')
        elif i in [1,n-1]:
            print('*', end='')
        else:
            print(' ', end='')
    print()
```

Alternatively, here's a "one line" solution.

```
n = 5
print('\n'.join([' '*(n-i-1)+'*'*(2*i+1) 
    if i in [0,1,n-1] 
    else (' '*(n-i-1)+'*'+' '*(2*i-1)+'*') 
    for i in range(n)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Add a condition which when the layer printing is 1, print '*'

Code:

```
def print_pyramid(total_layers):
    for current_layer in range(total_layers):
        
        for _ in range(total_layers - current_layer - 1):
            print(' ', end='')

        for column in range(2 * current_layer + 1):
            # if left bound, right bound, or the layer is the first or last layer, print '*'
            if column == 0 or column == 2*current_layer or current_layer == 1 or current_layer == total_layers-1:
                print('*', end='')
            else:
                print(' ', end='')

        print()

print_pyramid(5)
```

Output:

```
    *
   ***
  *   *
 *     *
*********
```